# How can I tell if an AsyncResult will never be ready?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

Scenario - I've got a process pool that I'm giving tasks. However, if a subprocess is killed while running a task, the `AsyncResult` object will never be marked as being ready. What I had hoped would happen is that it would be marked as ready and unsuccessful.

To reproduce this:

```
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> import time
>>> p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=1)
>>> result = p.apply_async(time.sleep, args=(1000,))
>>> result.ready()
False
```

In another shell, find the process id and kill it.

```
>>> result.ready()
False
>>> result.wait(5) # Waits 5 seconds even though subprocess is dead
```

This is an issue because I have a thread waiting on the job to finish, and it usually has a fairly long timeout. How do I get the `result.wait(timeout)` call to finish without needing to wait for the timeout? Also, how would I tell that it has been abandoned, and not just that the task is still running but we reached the timeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Pebble](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pebble) library notifies you if a process dies unexpectedly. It supports as well timeouts and callbacks.

Here's your example.

```
from pebble import ProcessPool
from concurrent.futures import TimeoutError

with ProcessPool() as pool:
    future = pool.schedule(time.sleep, args=(1000,), timeout=100)

    try:
        results = future.result()
        print(results)
    except TimeoutError as error:
        print("Function took longer than %d seconds" % error.args[1])
    except ProcessExpired as error:
        print("%s. Exit code: %d" % (error, error.exitcode))
    except Exception as error:
        print("function raised %s" % error)
        print(error.traceback)  # Python's traceback of remote process
```

More examples in the [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/Pebble/).

Comment: Yes I did. The Pool was added to the library due to the lack of an implementation capable to deal with timeouts and crashes. This was especially critical when running CPU intensive applications which limited duration could not be ensured. Other Use Case example were Python bindings of C libraries suffering from random segfaults crashing the entire application.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `result.wait()` will wait until it has reached `timeout` unless it gets a signal from the pool. However if you do `kill -9 [pid]` then the pool will immediately start the next job in the queue.

As such it's easier to utilize that and then manually "poll" and check `ready()`. The problem with that as you've stated is that `ready()` remains `False` when the job is killed.

To fix this you could check whether the pid is alive or not. Since `ApplyResult` doesn't carry the pid, you need other means to obtain it. You could do something like this:

```
def test(identifier):
    pid = os.getpid()

    f = open("pids/" + str(pid), "w")
    f.write(str(identifier))
    f.close()

    # do stuff
    time.sleep(1000)
```

Then creating the job like this (*Considering `jobs = []`*).

```
job = (identifier, pool.apply_async(test, (identifier,)))
jobs.append(job)
```

The identifier isn't needed but is useful if you later want to figure out which `ApplyResult` belongs to which pid.

You can then get all jobs and check if each job (pid) is alive:

```
def is_alive(pid):
    return os.path.exists("/proc/" + str(pid))

for pid in os.listdir("pids"):
    if is_alive(pid):
        ...
    else:
        ...
```

Considering the contents of each pid-named-file. Then using the `identifier` found in `jobs`, you can now link up which `ApplyResult` belongs to which pid and specifically check which job is dead or `ready()` or if none of the above then still running.

---

You can also create a pipe and fork a child process.

```
r, w = os.pipe()

def child():
    global r, w

    data = ...
    time.sleep(100)

    os.close(r)
    w = os.fdopen(w, "w")
    w.write(data)
    w.close()
```

You then just write the data back to your parent process.

```
def parent(child_pid):
    global r, w

    os.close(w)

    r = os.fdopen(r)
    data = r.read()
    r.close()

    status = os.waitpid(child_pid, 0)
    if status == 0:
        # Everything is fine
    elif status == 9:
        # kill -9 [pid]

    # Process data
```

You can then utilize the `status` and `data` received to decide what happened to the child process.

You start it all by doing.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    child_pid = os.fork()
    if child_pid:
        parent(child_pid)
    else:
        child()
```

<sup>*From your question I'm assuming Unix. If not feel free to correct me. Also if any non-Python 2.7 sneaked into the answer, then I apologize.*</sup>